# duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown> when deploying flow with custom error

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment, recordtriggeredflow, deployment-error

When I attempt to deploy a record-triggered flow with a custom error message element to a UAT sandbox, the validation phase fails with the vague error: "duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id: " when the flow includes Custom Error element. However, if I remove the custom error message element, there are no issues.

I have searched for solutions without any success.

I am using GitHub Actions to deploy from one sandbox to another.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solve, it was an API versioning issue.
I had to change the sourceApiVersion on the sfdx-project.json file to 59.0 since custom error message is released on version 59.0 and then deploy again